# How do I make a list of items where each item has associated information in Android?

Tags: java, android

How do I make a list of items where each item has associated information in Android?

For example, I want to be able to have a list of countries and then be able to click on the country and find the population, language, w/e associated with that country.

I found this the following link with shows how to make a simple list but not how to click on an item and get the information associated with the county.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

How do I do this without making a database, which seems like overkill to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make your list of Strings, and then you can make a `HashMap

like so:

```
class PopulationInformation {

    // add fields
    String name;
    int population;
    String language;

    //pretend there's a constructor

    // should override hashcode and equals, but right now
    // default works
}
```

then later you can do

```
Map<String,PopulationInformation> map = new HashMap<String,PopulationInformation>();
map.put("United States",new PopulationInformation("United States",320000000,"Engish"));
map.put("Canada",new PopulationInformation("Canada",30000000,"French/Engish"));
```

then when you select something on the list

```
String selected = ... // how did you select?
PopulationInformation info = map.get(selected);
String infoString = info.name + "'s population is " + info.population 
                  + ". They speak " + info.language + ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a **custom list adapter**:

- **send** it the ArrayList of your countries
- **display** the field "name" of your country objects in the list elements (inside the adapter, see the link below).
- **bind** a listener to the list to react when the user clicks.

When the user eventually clicks on an item you will get the country object and do some further processing with it.

**Alternatively**, make a hashmap that maps the relationship between the names of the countries and the actual objects they represent and refer to it when you need to do the mapping.

**List adapter:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just set up a Country object with private members that you want to store, then use ListView/ListActivity to display the Countries?

There's a tutorial by Vogella [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Section 4 covers most of the stuff that you'll need.